# which mail -s команда не найдена

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

Выполняю скрипт, все вроде бы нормально в нем:

```
# Команда для отправки почты
MAILCMD="$(which mail)"
# Файл письма
MAILMESSAGE="/tmp/service.fail.$$"
# Email, куда слать уведомления
EMAILID="test217opg@gmail.ru"

# Функция для отправки письма
mail_doxer()
{
$MAILCMD -s "Уведомление о проблемах запуска сервисов $(hostname)" $EMAILID < $MAILMESSAGE
}

echo "Данное письмо отправлено Вам, так как были обнаружены проблемы">>$MAILMESSAGE
echo "на АРМЕ $(hostname), а Ваш адрес указан в скрипте для таких уведомлений">>$MAILMESSAGE
echo "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >>$MAILMESSAGE
echo "">>$MAILMESSAGE
```

На выводе ошибка:

```
script.sh: строка 17: -s: команда не найдена
```

Не знаю куда копать :(

Comment: Вы не проверяете результат which. Он очевидно не нашёл ничего и вернул пустую строку.

Comment: И  как это исправить ? Вы знаете?

Comment: Дописать в скрипт проверку. Потом поставить MTA чтобы mail появился. Да и вообще настроить полноценный мониторинг вместо этого.

Answer (score 2):

ошибка вызвана тем, что в переменной `MAILCMD` — пусто.

проверить это просто. например:

```
if [ -z "${MAILCMD}" ]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

а пусто в ней потому, что программа *which* ничего не вернула в *stdout* и завершилась с ошибкой.

проверить это просто. например:

```
MAILCMD="$(which mail)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...; else ...; fi
```

а завершилась с ошибкой программа *which* потому, что не нашла исполнимого файла (или символической ссылки, ведущей в конце концов к к какому-нибудь исполнимому файлу) с указанным именем (`mail`) ни в одном из каталогов, перечисленных в переменной окружения `PATH` пользователя, запустившего эту программу.

---

вообще в дистрибутиве *debian gnu/linux* символическую ссылку `/usr/bin/mail` предоставляют по крайней мере два пакета: `bsd-mailx` и `mailutils`. но установка этих пакетов скорее всего — совсем не то, что вам требуется (а требуется вам, скорее всего, какая-нибудь реализация [smtp](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMTP)-сервера).